# 401(unauthorised) while making service call

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Getting 401(authorised)  while making web api controller call

```
public bool CheckCarrierSCAC(int carrierID)
        {
            bool carrierScacSatus = false;
            carrierSCAC = new BackOfficeViewController().GetSCACCodeBYCarrierID(carrierID);
            logger.LogMessage(message: string.Format("Credentials {0}{1}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HermesUserName"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HermesPassword"]), logDate: true);
            Http.Preauthenticate = true;
            string serviceUrl = string.Format("{0}/CarrierSCAC?carrier={1}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GatewayInterface"], carrierSCAC);
            logger.LogMessage(message: string.Format("Check Carrier SCAC Service URL {0} ", serviceUrl), logDate: true);
            try
            {
                carrierScacSatus = Http.Get<bool>(uri: serviceUrl, cookieContainer: null, contentType: "application/json");
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                logger.LogException(exception, message: "error while check Carrier Scac =" + exception.Message);
            }
            return carrierScacSatus;
        }
```

I have already used preauthentication still getting same error

Comment: check about CORS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `Http.Preauthenticate = true` just tells the web request to send the `Authorization` header to that Uri going forward, assuming it's a pass-through to [.NET's `HttpWebRequest.Preauthenticate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.preauthenticate(v=vs.110).aspx).  In this case, you don't appear to actually be providing any credentials to the web request. The only case where you reference the credentials is in the logger message.

The `Http.Get<T>` method should allow you to provide either raw Header values (in which case you'll need to add your own `Authorization` header) or the credentials so that it creates the header for you. (This appears to be a library that wraps the C# `WebRequest` or some similar connection library, so you'll need to check it's documentation for specific details).

Comment: @SandeepPandey did that fix your issue, or is it still giving you 401s?

Comment: Excellent! Please remember to mark the answer as accepted if it addressed your question. Thanks.